# why mod_rewrite redirects to absolute path from www.foo.com/phpmyadmin/ to www.foo.com/usr/share/phpmyadmin

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I think my problems came after upgrading apache or something like that. So here is my .htaccess

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ([\d]+)-.+-([\d]+).html showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ([\d]+)-.+.html showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subdomains/.* - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.foo\.com
RewriteRule ^$ subdomains/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.foo.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.foo.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb  1 2014 21:22:42
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9

Comment: Add an appropriate `RewriteBase` directive below `RewriteEngine`

Comment: Yes I found your example here and I tried this http://www.mobilfunk-talk.de/htaccess.txt you can test with: http://webapp1.mobilfunk-talk.de/phpmyadmin/ normally this url should be work

Comment: @anubhav do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I know for sure that is the problem. You probably have a bad browser cache.